# No injectable members-error when using more than one dagger module in project

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I would really like to implement Dagger in my app but I have a hard time to understand how it should be configured correctly.
I have two classes that I would like to inject.

```
public class LoginController {
    @Inject Bus bus;
    @Inject Context context;
    // more code 
}

public class LoginFragment {
    @Inject Bus bus;
    // more code
}
```

If I put all my code in one module it works fine:

```
@Module(injects = {LoginController.class, LoginFragment.class})
public class BasicModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Bus busProvider() {
        return new Bus();
    }
    @Provides
    public Context provideContext() {
        return RblMobileApp.getContext();
    }
}
```

But when I put those methods in two different modules (BasicModule and TestModule) I get compiler errors:

```
@Module(injects = {LoginController.class, LoginFragment.class})
public class BasicModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Bus busProvider() {
        return new Bus();
    }
}

Error:(18, 8) java: No injectable members on android.content.Context. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by rblmobile.controllers.LoginController for rblmobile.injection.BasicModule 

@Module(injects = {LoginController.class})
public class TestModule {
    @Provides
    public Context provideContext() {
        return RblMobileApp.getContext();
    }
}

Error:(13, 8) java: No injectable members on com.squareup.otto.Bus. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by rblmobile.controllers.LoginController for rblmobile.injection.TestModule
```

So basically I'm told that BasicModule doesn't deliever Context and TestModule doesn't deliever Bus. Why does the ObjectGraph not know that the respective Constructor is in the other module?

Thanks

EDIT:
That's the method where the ObjectGraph gets created.

```
public static void init(final Object... modules) {
    Log.i(TAG, "initializing object graph");

    if (objectGraph == null) {
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(modules);
    } else {
        objectGraph = objectGraph.plus(modules);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `@Module` annotation attribute called [complete](http://square.github.io/dagger/javadoc/dagger/Module.html#complete%28%29). Try to set it to `false`:

```
@Module(complete = false, injects = {LoginController.class, LoginFragment.class})
public class BasicModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Bus busProvider() {
        return new Bus();
    }
}

@Module(complete = false, injects = {LoginController.class})
public class TestModule {
    @Provides
    public Context provideContext() {
        return RblMobileApp.getContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks makovkastar, it's working now. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695515/dagger-cant-find-injectable-members-on-a-module?rq=1 describes a similar problem with some explanations by a square developer.